# Who introduced the concept of beyond planar graphs?

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory, ho.history-overview, planar-graphs, graph-drawing

The concept of planar graphs seems to be standard (I'm also not sure who first used this term), and recently, beyond planar graphs attract a lot of interest in the field of graph drawing. I know that this concept can be traced back to this report (https://drops.dagstuhl.de/opus/volltexte/2019/10863/) or the book *Beyond Planar Graphs: Communications of NII Shonan Meetings*, but I would like to know its origins.  Who formally introduced this standard term?

> Beyond-planar graphs, i.e., non-planar graphs that admit a drawing
> with topological constraints such as specific types of crossings or
> with some forbidden crossing patterns.

Comment: an earlier (2016) [Dagstuhl meeting](https://drops.dagstuhl.de/opus/volltexte/2017/7038/pdf/dagrep_v006_i011_p035_s16452.pdf) may be the first explicit mention of this term

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A pre-Dagstuhl reference is

[Graph drawing beyond planarity: some results and open problems.](https://ceur-ws.org/Vol-1231/proceedings.pdf#page=10)
G Liotta,ICTCS 14, 3-8 (2014).

> The “beyond planarity” research area could be briefly described as the
> (potentially uncountable) collection of problems of the type
> depicted in the figure, where the column ”Forbidden” describes a
> forbidden crossing configuration and the column ”Question” describes a
> corresponding computational question of interest in graph drawing.

[image]

Comment: Thank you.  It appears that your literature is relatively early. The 1-planar graphs (as a subclass of beyond planar graphs) can be traced back to Ringel, but it's probably quite challenging to trace its earliest origins for beyond planar graphs, even though it has gained popularity in recent years.